# Spring Boot app steadily allocating memory even if not in use

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection, profiling

I have a simple Spring Boot app with a few REST endpoints which basically pass data to a database and have no other logic whatsoever.

Now in VisualVM profiler I see that memory consumption steadily increases (like 1 Mb / 5 seconds) even if nothing happens - no requests are coming to the API.

Those are not memory leaks, 'cause triggering GC frees them but I'm still concerned on what is happening and whether it's a suspicious thing?

Comment: Does this memory graph eventually flatten out? Or does it keep increasing indefinitely until an OOM error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after further experiments the answer was simple: I checked the threads which were allocating and found out those were the threads which communicate with the VisualVM profiler !! ;)